# Replacement rules with list as matching

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

How can I use replacement rules to match and work with a list.  For example,

```
{1, {2, 3}} /. {{a_, b_} -> ((a + # &) /@ b)}
```

outputs

```
{2,3}
```

but I  expected

```
{3,4}
```

Comment: change `->` to `:>` as in `/. {{a_, b_} :> ((a + # &) /@ b)}`

Comment: Thank you - why did this work?

Answer (score 3):

Lists have nothing to do with the problem. The reason why you obtained the result above is that `->` (`Rule`) evaluates its arguments before going further. So

```
(a + # &) /@ b
```

inside your rule first evaluated to

```
b
```

resulting in the rule

```
{a_, b_} -> b
```

and only after that the replacement

```
{1, {2, 3}} /. {{a_, b_} -> b}
```

evaluated to `{2, 3}`. You can use `:>` (`RuleDelayed`) to prevent the second argument of `:>` from evaluation:

```
{1, {2, 3}} /. {{a_, b_} :> ((a + # &) /@ b)}
(*{3, 4}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `b` with a head `List` works

```
{1, {2, 3}} /. {a_, b_List} -> a + b
```

But why not just use `Plus`:

```
Plus @@ {1, {2, 3}}
```